# Relationship of R/S signature in between signed message and DER signature

Tags: signature, message-signing, message-verification

this time is difficult for me to explain problem i was facing. i realize that R/S signature in DER signature is not match to the 1 in bitcoin signed message? Ok below is my say signed message.

```
-----BEGIN BITCOIN SIGNED MESSAGE-----
c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
-----BEGIN SIGNATURE-----
1BxqqjVC29fvCWin4qBuqZhBy4V7Ncdxby
        IPnTEOU713+XclrBrUEfTLeP0A7QIR4lObzQjBjyxGQExPwkalrQK1JOggIWk4xrfWIjHEC0RKGv3vtguDfto0o=
-----END BITCOIN SIGNED MESSAGE-----
```

my working way is $decoded_content = bin2hex(base64_decode(IPnTEOU713+XclrBrUEfTLeP0A7QIR4lObzQjBjyxGQExPwkalrQK1JOggIWk4xrfWIjHEC0RKGv3vtguDfto0o=))

then i manage to get R/S signature from $decoded_content. after that, i use R/S signature to generate DER signature. I realized that this DER signature is fail in signature verification.

shortly to say,

my program check valid signature using function in https://github.com/tuaris/CryptoCurrencyPHP/blob/master/Wallet.class.php#L225

if another party send me DER signature, how do i convert it into base64_encoded string? so end up i am able to use function i mention just now.

I try alot of methods but no luck, are R/S signature in both signed message and DER signature means to same?

please help

Comment: r and s are not points. They both are the signature, but not a point on the curve. r, however, is the x coordinate of the point R which calculated like this:  (z/s)G + (r/s)P = kG = R. G is the originator point of the secp256k1, P is the public key point on the curve. z is the signature hash of the transaction, and k is a "random" value to generate the signature (in reality k is deterministic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoin *transactions* use DER format for the signature (plus sighash byte), but bitcoin *messages* use 'plain' format (aka P1363, CVC, PKCS11, Microsoft, JWS and more) (plus recovery byte). The computation of the r,s *values* in an  ECDSA (which as Oscar correctly commented are *not* a point) is the same either way, but the data being signed for a message can never be the same as for a transaction so the signatures can never actually be the same value.

Your signature should not be and is not in DER format. The code you link to appears correct:

```
    $signature = base64_decode($encodedSignature);

    $flag = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($signature, 0, 1)));

    $R = bin2hex(substr($signature, 1, 32));
    $S = bin2hex(substr($signature, 33));
```

That correctly parses a plain-format signature (not DER), from base64.

```
    $derPubKey = Signature::getPubKeyWithRS($flag, $R, $S, $hash);
```

Without tracking down the code this calls, that looks like it should recover and encode the pubkey; whether it also verifies the signature is not obvious.